# Time complexity with bit cost

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of studying an algorithm's time complexity with respect to **bit cost** (instead of unit cost) and it seems to be impossible to find anything on the subject.

Here's what I have so far:

The bit cost of multiplication and division of two numbers with n bits is, with arbitrary arithmetics, O(n^2).

So, for example:

```
int number = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    number = i*i;
}
```

has a time complexity with respect to bit cost of O(log(n)^2*n), because it does n multiplications and `i` has `log(i)` bits.

But in a regular scenario we want the time complexity with respect to the input. So, how does that scenario work? The number of bits in `i` could be considered a constant. Which would make the time complexity the same as with unit cost except with a bigger constant (and therefore both would be linear).

Addition, subtraction, comparisons and assigning variables are all O(n), n being the number of bits, for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With limited precision arithmetic (like the most-probably 32 bit `int` multiplication in your example) the bit cost of multiplication is constant. The cost of multiplying two `int` is `O(32^2)` using a naive multiplication algorithm (for better algos look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)). This is the same as `O(1)` so people usually neglect to mention it when analysing algorithms.

If we use arbitrary precision arithmetic however, then it becomes important. If an arbitrarily long number with a value of `i` was stored in bits, it would take up `O(log(i))` bits. So the cost of your code snippet would be `O(log(n)^2 * n)` (I'm using the fact that all `i` are no larger than `n` since your loop goes up to `n`).

As far as addition and subtraction goes I would say that they both have a bit cost of `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of bits of the smaller operand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very informative. Any thoughts on the case with time complexity with respect to the input (and bit cost)?

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the time complexity with respect to input scenario. If we assume the number of bits is constant, we end up with a runtime that is linear with a larger constant, just like you wrote. Asymptotically, the larger constant does not matter so runtime stays linear with respect to input.